# Int to byte array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, int32

I thought .net had some kind of easy conversion method to use for converting an int into a byte array? I did a quick search and all solutions are bit masking/shifting one byte at a time, like "the good ol days". 
Is there not a ToByteArray() method somewhere?

Answer (score 143, accepted):

Update for 2020 - [`BinaryPrimitives`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.binary.binaryprimitives?view=netcore-3.1) should now be preferred over `BitConverter`. It provides endian-specific APIs, and is less allocatey.

---

```
byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(i);
```

although note also that you *might* want to check `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian` to see which way around that is going to appear!

Note that if you are doing this *repeatedly* you might want to avoid all those short-lived array allocations by writing it yourself via either shift operations (`>>` / `<<`), or by using `unsafe` code. Shift operations *also* have the advantage that they aren't affected by your platform's endianness; you *always* get the bytes in the order you expect them.

Comment: +1: For clarity, I would replace in "[...] in the order you expect them" with "big-endian".

Comment: Why does `BitConverter.GetBytes(250)` return `[250,0,0,0]`, and not `[250]`?

 `Byte.MaxValue == 255`, right?

Comment: @Tobi because you're calling GetBytes(int) - so: 4 bytes, and your CPU is little-endian. There would be no purpose in a GetBytes (byte) method.

Comment: @Tobi re GetBytes(256): you don't get 255,1 because it is explicitly the fixed width representation - bytes. The little-endian (your CPU) fixed width 32 bit representation of 256 is what you'll get

Comment: hi Marc, which approach will provider even slightly better performance, `bitwise` or `unsafe`?

Comment: @Timeless *usually*: `unsafe` - but it varies depending on *exactly* what you're doing - the best thing to do would be to implement it twice and test 10-million or so of both, timing them

Comment: How does one inverse the order of the array if it is little Endian?

I want it to be in the order `00-00-00-01` not `01-00-00-00`

Comment: @Zapnologica for that I would recommend `BinaryPrimitives` - it has endian-specific encode and decode operations. It didn't exist when I posted this answer, but does now. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.binary.binaryprimitives?view=netcore-3.1

Answer (score 40):

Marc's answer is of course the right answer. But since he mentioned the shift operators and unsafe code as an alternative. I would like to share a less common alternative. Using a struct with `Explicit` layout. This is similar in principal to a C/C++ `union`.

Here is an example of a struct that can be used to get to the component bytes of the Int32 data type and the nice thing is that it is two way, you can manipulate the byte values and see the effect on the Int.

```
  using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

  [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
  struct Int32Converter
  {
    [FieldOffset(0)] public int Value;
    [FieldOffset(0)] public byte Byte1;
    [FieldOffset(1)] public byte Byte2;
    [FieldOffset(2)] public byte Byte3;
    [FieldOffset(3)] public byte Byte4;

    public Int32Converter(int value)
    {
      Byte1 = Byte2 = Byte3 = Byte4 = 0;
      Value = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator Int32(Int32Converter value)
    {
      return value.Value;
    }

    public static implicit operator Int32Converter(int value)
    {
      return new Int32Converter(value);
    }
  }
```

The above can now be used as follows

```
 Int32Converter i32 = 256;
 Console.WriteLine(i32.Byte1);
 Console.WriteLine(i32.Byte2);
 Console.WriteLine(i32.Byte3);
 Console.WriteLine(i32.Byte4);

 i32.Byte2 = 2;
 Console.WriteLine(i32.Value);
```

Of course the immutability police may not be excited about the last possiblity :)

Comment: +1: This is a nice approach. If you're worried about the immutability police, you could make the fields private and expose them with get-only properties.

Comment: @Ani, Thanks, that is a good idea to make the `byte` members private and create get-only properties.

Comment: The statement(s) 'Byte1 = Byte2 = Byte3 = Byte4 = 0;' are redundant as the subsequent Value assignment overwrites them.
This is precisely the kind of aliasing that drives compiler optimiser writers nuts.
The union is elegant as it collapses the multiple writes to a single one through the memory channel.
Using the struct also avoids the array allocation for extremely frequent cases.

Comment: @Pekka, the compiler enforces that you initialize all members of the struct and it does not take into account the fact that the bytes are overlaid by the int which is why the initialization is required, redundant but required.

Comment: @Chris, true, precisely the optimiser police fighting with the aliases.

Comment: Isn't this solution susceptible to the big/little endian difficulty, too? If you are on a big endian system, the content of the "Value" field will be reversed, right?

Comment: @eikuh, absolutely, Bitconverter.IsLittleEndian can help with determining the correct order to read the bytes. BUT, like I said this is no the right answer, I just shared it because at the time the technique was not widely seen.

Comment: @ChrisTaylor, where did you say it's not the right answer?

Comment: @eikuh, the first sentence "Marc's answer is of course the right answer." and the rest of that paragraph explains why I shared this. Now, that is not to say that it is not the right answer for another problem, but for the original question I think Marc's answer is correct. I hope that helps.

Comment: By using this answer you can remove the redundant statement "byte1 = byte2 = byte3 = byte4 = 0" and also speed up the code for one or two nanoseconds https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9174787/struct-layout-explicit-constructor-fully-assign-fields
I also implemented this, that may be useful for those who thing this method is a good idea:
https://gist.github.com/forestrf/e421166fc32ef707fe3817360d711a61

Answer (score 2):

This may be OT but if you are serializing a lot of primitive types or POD structures, [Google Protocol Buffers for .Net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) might be useful to you.  This addresses the endianness issue @Marc raised above, among other useful features.

Answer (score 2):

**If you came here from Google**

Alternative answer to an older question refers to John Skeet's Library that has tools for letting you write primitive data types directly into a byte[] with an Index offset. Far better than `BitConverter` if you need performance.

[Older thread discussing this issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287143/simplest-way-to-copy-int-to-byte)

[John Skeet's Libraries are here](http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/miscutil/)

Just download the source and look at the `MiscUtil.Conversion` namespace.  `EndianBitConverter.cs` handles everything for you.

Answer (score 1):

Heap allocation free using [MemoryMarshal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.memorymarshal) and [Span](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1)

```cs
int messageLen = 1111;
Span<byte> messageTypeBytes = MemoryMarshal.AsBytes(MemoryMarshal.CreateSpan(ref messageLen, 1));
```

**BenchmarkDotnet**

```
|            Method |      Mean |     Error |    StdDev | Allocated |
|------------------ |----------:|----------:|----------:|----------:|
| MemoryMarshalTest | 0.0023 ns | 0.0017 ns | 0.0014 ns |         - |
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers here are either 'UnSafe" or not LittleEndian safe. BitConverter is not LittleEndian safe.
So building on an example in [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/3928b8cb-3703-4672-8ccd-33718148d1e3/) (see the post by PZahra) I made a LittleEndian safe version simply by reading the byte array in reverse when BitConverter.IsLittleEndian == true

```
void Main(){    
    Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.IsLittleEndian); 
    byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(0xdcbaabcdfffe1608);
    //Console.WriteLine(bytes); 
    string hexStr = ByteArrayToHex(bytes);
    Console.WriteLine(hexStr);
}

public static string ByteArrayToHex(byte[] data) 
{ 
   char[] c = new char[data.Length * 2]; 
   byte b; 
  if(BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
  {
        //read the byte array in reverse
        for (int y = data.Length -1, x = 0; y >= 0; --y, ++x) 
        { 
            b = ((byte)(data[y] >> 4)); 
            c[x] = (char)(b > 9 ? b + 0x37 : b + 0x30); 
            b = ((byte)(data[y] & 0xF)); 
            c[++x] = (char)(b > 9 ? b + 0x37 : b + 0x30); 
        }               
    }
    else
    {
        for (int y = 0, x = 0; y < data.Length; ++y, ++x) 
        { 
            b = ((byte)(data[y] >> 4)); 
            c[x] = (char)(b > 9 ? b + 0x37 : b + 0x30); 
            b = ((byte)(data[y] & 0xF)); 
            c[++x] = (char)(b > 9 ? b + 0x37 : b + 0x30); 
        }
    }
    return String.Concat("0x",new string(c));
}
```

It returns this:

```
True
0xDCBAABCDFFFE1608
```

which is the exact hex that went into the byte array.

Comment: It doesn't start from an int, though. Not to mention, it's a lot more logical to do that endianness check on _read_ so you're sure what your data is like in the array.