# Convert object to byte array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays

I want to convert object value to byte array in c#.

EX:

```
 step 1. Input : 2200
 step 2. After converting Byte : 0898
 step 3. take first byte(08)

 Output: 08
```

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Int to byte array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176653/int-to-byte-array)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may take a look at the [GetBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de8fssa4.aspx) method:

```
int i = 2200;
byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(i);
Console.WriteLine(bytes[0].ToString("x"));
Console.WriteLine(bytes[1].ToString("x"));
```

Also make sure you have taken [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) into consideration in your definition of *first byte*.

Answer (score 4):

```
byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(2200);
Console.WriteLine(bytes[0]);
```

Answer (score 4):

Using [`BitConverter.GetBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.getbytes.aspx) will convert your integer to a `byte[]` array using the system's native endianness.

```
short s = 2200;
byte[] b = BitConverter.GetBytes(s);

Console.WriteLine(b[0].ToString("X"));    // 98 (on my current system)
Console.WriteLine(b[1].ToString("X"));    // 08 (on my current system)
```

If you need explicit control over the endianness of the conversion then you'll need to do it manually:

```
short s = 2200;
byte[] b = new byte[] { (byte)(s >> 8), (byte)s };

Console.WriteLine(b[0].ToString("X"));    // 08 (always)
Console.WriteLine(b[1].ToString("X"));    // 98 (always)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int number = 2200;
byte[] br = BitConverter.GetBytes(number);
```