# Struct - Layout.Explicit - Constructor - fully assign fields

Tags: c#, struct

Why if i use:

```
struct MyStruct
{
        [FieldOffset (0)] public uint Data;
        [FieldOffset (0)] public byte Something;
}

public MyStruct (uint pData)
{
   Data = pData; // setting Data field also sets Something field
}
```

C# says i need to assign 'Something' field :/ I know I can do a "Constructor : this ()"
but compiler should know 'Data' field contains 'Something' field.

So, I should call parameterless constructor first, is it the only way?

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you'll need to call the default constructor.

```
public MyStruct (uint pData) : this()
{
   //...
}
```

The compiler will then generate the following IL instructions at the beginning of your constructor:

```
ldarg.0           // Push address of struct onto stack
initobj MyStruct  // Pop address of struct and initialize it with "all zeros"
```

Comment: This is very useful. Doing this speeds up the code by one or more nanoseconds (depending on how many fields are).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it is not possible, and the discussion about it has been closed down:

Here is a link to the discussion regarding this issue:

https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/7323

Answer (score -2):

You need to initialize all of the fields of a struct if you define a custom constructor. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288471%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) MSDN tutorial in structs for more information - specifically under the Constructors and Inheritence heading.

Here is an paragraph extracted from that link with regards to this:

> Structs can declare constructors, but they must take parameters. It is an error to declare a default (parameterless) constructor for a struct. Struct members cannot have initializers. A default constructor is always provided to initialize the struct members to their default values.

Comment: I'm talking about something else.

Comment: @zgnilec In that case I would suggest reviewing your question as it doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Well, maybe someone else will understand me.